# Is the phrase "there are no remainings of X" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Example sentence:

> There are no remainings of the chicken in the pot.

Remainings is underlined with red in most textareas and software. It there something ungrammatical? If so, what's the correct version?

Answer (score 1):

*remaining* needs to modify something. Those things (as a noun) could be called *remains*. You could use:

> There are no **remains** of the chicken in the pot.

but this sounds rather morbid. Better would be:

> There *is* no **remaining chicken** in the pot.

Here *remaining* modifies *chicken*.

*chicken* as used above is singular, unless there is more than one chicken. But you could say:

> There *are* no remaining chicken thighs in the pot.